# Do we need to upload universal-apk if we are uploading different apk's for each ABI

Tags: android, performance, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, abi

My app size has reached to 117 MB, as play store does not allow to upload an apks, if its greater than [100 MB](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html).

So i used `split`, and created multiple versions of apk each based on different [ABI](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split)

If i analyze `universal-apk`, i got these type of `ABI's` in lib folder;

- armeabi-v7a
- x86
- armeabi

[image]

I used this to create `separate apk` for each `abi`

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Now i get 4 types of apk in result. The `universal-apk` size is 117 MB, where as `armeabi` is 68 MB.

[image]

So its obvious from this, that i just can't upload the `universal-apk` on play store, hence i will end up uploading `3 apk's` on play store.

Now my questions is what will happen to those users whose `cpu architecture` do not fall into these categories.

I noticed that Galaxy S7 is `arm64-v8a`, there will be some other architectures available in the market other than these, so what will happen to those devices if `universal-apk` does not exist, or `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` are enough to target all of the devices available in the market.

Will this reduce target app users? I am unable to find out the `ABI share on Google Play`

Comment: Can you include arm64-v8a to your abi definitions?

Comment: It looks like if you remove reset and include then all abi's that are supported for the store will be built. Is this a valid approach for you?

Comment: yes, i can include all of these, but the size of all other `apk's` is way smaller than others, except `armeab-v7a` and `x86` all other architectures don't have any `.so` files, so i am afraid if adding separate apk's for each of them can lead to crashes, thats why i asked, if `armeab-v7a` and `x86`  are enough to support all available devices in the market.

Comment: Perhaps the other architectures have those dependencies included on the device? I am not an expert abi splits, but given your observation about the S7 I would say that you would need to include all abis if you want to support all available devices.

Comment: let me give you an example, some external library needed to use `libUnity.so`, they added `libUnity.so` in both `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` folder. so universal-apk has 2 `linunity.so` files, and its increasing the size of  universal-apk, thats the reason i split apk, and both architecture now have only 1 `linUnity.so` file.

Comment: The other architectures might not have as big of library dependencies. Have you tried it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is always to work from data. Have a look at your existing users in the Play Developer Console to see what the distribution is like for your users.

For users without one of these ABIs they will get "This app is not compatible with your device".

However, x86_64 and arm64-v8a are backwards compatilble with x86 and armeabi-v7a. By covering the ones you have chosen it will run on almost all devices, mips probably isn't worth worrying about.

Your users on newer devices will get better performance if you add x86_64 and arm64-v8a variants as well, but it should work without this.

armeabi is now very rare but some very old devices do have that restriction. If you are targeting a modern android version (eg ICS+) you will probably be ok.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, one more question, can `armeabi` devices run `armeabi-v7a` files, and will it be fine if i don't upload a separate apk for `armeabi` devices, as all the `.so` files that i have are targeting either `x86` or `armeabi-v7a` devices.

Comment: Edited to add more detail. I'd guess you will be fine with only armeabi-v7a if you have a relatively new min-SDK (eg ICS+). But you should look at your existing users in the stats in the Play console.

Comment: I have a question, if you don't mind. `However, x86_64 and arm64-v8a are backwards compatilble with x86 and armeabi-v7a.` - Does this mean that I can leave out `x86` and only add `x86_64`? Currently my abi filter is - `abiFilters "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"`

Answer (score 1):

A list of all the supported ABI's can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa

If you remove the reset() option, then the splits will be built for each supported ABI.